# Mocking dependencies of dependencies in Karma testing

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, karma-mocha

-I've seen many questions around testing and DI, but none that has helped me so far.

I have a module:

```
angular
  .module('app.users', ['app.auth', 'app.foo']);
```

and simple service with a function I want to test:

```
(function(){
  angular
    .module('app.users')
    .factory('UsersModel', UsersModel);

UsersModel.$inject = ["AuthService", "FooService"]

  function UsersModel(AuthService, FooService){
    function someFunction(){
      // do stuff...
  }
}

})();
```

And a test file:

```
describe("Users", function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    module('app.users');
    angular.mock.module('app.auth'); // includes AuthService
    angular.mock.module('app.foo'); // include FooService
  })

  describe("Username", function(){
    it("should do stuff", inject(function(UsersModel){
      // no code here
    }));
  });
});
```

Now, the service `FooService` itself depends on `BarService`. When I run this in karma, I get an error:

```
Unknown provider: BarServiceProvider <- BarService <- FooService <- UsersModel
```

And this confuses me: since I use `angular.mock.module('app.foo')`, I would have expected the dependencies of `fooService` to not even be on the radar. Apparently they are though, so I'm thinking that I'm doing something wrong.

How should I go about dealing with my service's dependencies? Should I stub `FooService`?

Comment: Where is the BarService defined? Which module? And how is the app.foo module defined?

Comment: I was going to refactor my code anyway, and doing so allowed to not need the module that was causing trouble